# filas incompletas en JS con ciclo FOR

Tags: javascript

Si son 50 filas, ¿Por que JS recorre 49 filas? este es mi código

```js
var todoCorrecto = true;
var formulario = document.enviaComision;
for (var w = 1; w < formulario.length; w++) {
  if (formulario[w].type == 'text') {
    if (formulario[w].value == "") {
      console.log(w);

      todoCorrecto = false;
    }
  }
}
```

¿Como le haría para que recorra las 50 filas?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los índices de los [arrays en JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) comienzan en `0` no en `1`. Por lo tanto debes inicializar `var w = 0` en el `for`

```
var todoCorrecto = true;
var formulario = document.enviaComision;
for (var w = 0; w < formulario.length; w++) {
  if (formulario[w].type == 'text') {
    if (formulario[w].value == "") {
      console.log(w);

      todoCorrecto = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: y como se puede hacer para que comience en 1 o ya esta definido en 0?

Comment: En Javascript y en la mayoría de lenguajes,  sí esta definido que comiencen en 0. Pero esto no suele ser problema,  si necesitas el número de iteración simplemente define i = w + 1 dentro del for y listo

Answer (score 1):

Talvez `var formulario = document.enviaComision;` es un array y al momento de recorrerlo no estas iniciando `var w = 0;` en la ciclo for `for (var w = 1; w < formulario.length; w++) {` Intenta cambiadolo en 0 la variable w.

Pero de igual forma te dejo otro ejemplo, espero te sirva:

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll("form input[type='text']"); //buscamos todos los input's de tipo text que esten dentro del form
for(var b in a) // como nos entrega un Array, entonces recorremos ó iteramos
{
  var c = a[b];
  if(typeof c == "object"){ //verificamos que todo sea un objeto
    console.log(a.item(b),b); // Imprimimos el item de la posición b y tambien la posición del array b.
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="miformulario">

  <input type="text" name="uno" />
  <input type="text" name="dos" />
  <input type="text" name="tres" />
  <input type="text" name="cuatro" />
  <input type="text" name="cinco" />
  <input type="text" name="seis" />
  <input type="text" name="siete" />
  <input type="text" name="ocho" />
  <input type="text" name="nueve" />
  <input type="text" name="diez" />
</form>
```

Comment: lo sigue mostrando en 49

Comment: Coloca tu html por favor

Comment: Hola Ivxn, por favor coloca tu código para poder revisarlo y con todo gusto te apoyo. Saludos.

Comment: abrire un post nuevo para colocar solo el codigo correpondiente

Comment: ok lo busco cuando lo postees...